# Create a Timer and display Error Message once when time's out in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I want to create a timer of 20 seconds. 
When it reaches 20 second, it will pop out a error message with OK button.
After user click ok, it will close the whole application and exit completely.

My code is as follows. However, the error message will be pop out continuously for 5 times within 5 seconds.

How do I make the error message displayed once only instead of 5 times?

```
private void SetTimerUSBPort()     
{
// Create a timer with a 20 second interval.
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(20000);      //Timer is in ms 
aTimer.Interval = 20000;

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
DialogResult result;
bool display;

display = true;

// Check if USB Port Driver found, Progress Bar reached Max
if (DetectCommPort.IsUSBPortPresent == true)
{
    buttonAutoDetectingNext.Enabled = true;                                   
    aTimer.Stop();
    aTimer.Enabled = false;

}

//If USB Port Driver not setup and reach 3 minutes:
else
{

    aTimer.Stop();
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    buttonAutoDetectingNext.Enabled = false;  


    this.timerProgressBar.Enabled = false;


    if (display == true) 
    {
        display = false;
        if (MessageBox.Show("A problem was detected when attempting to configure the USB port. \n" +
            "Please exit this setup and reinstall the BPro USB drivers. \n You can then rerun this setup process.\n",
            "", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {


            // Exit the application. Close everything down.
            Application.Exit();    

            return;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Cheers,
PF

Comment: When and how many times are you calling `SetTimerUSBPort()`?

Comment: Can't you just put a boolean that you set to false after the alert box comes up, and is required to be true for any of the other timer related functions to get activated?

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
adv12, I call SetTimerUSBPort() once. I called it at wrong place. After call it at correct place, the error message displayed once only.